# Illustrator - communicating with printing company

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, print-production, artboard

I want to send some artwork (signs) to a printing company - about 20 designs, with varying quantities printed.

Each sign  is on it's own artboard in illustrator. What is the best way to clearly communicate the quantities of each sign to the printer?

My thoughts are there would be a way to create some sort of non-printable annotation on each artboard that expresses the desired quantity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send each print project *separately*. That means split your AI document into 1 artboard per project. And you can then designate the quantity desired for FileXXXX.pdf, etc.

With varying quantities, relying on *any* other method is a recipe for errors.

Answer (score 2):

NEVER EVER EVER EVER send an open file type for printing. Always send closed files like pdf, ps, eps, tiff, even jpg.

Prepare pdf of every artboard. Use free plugins and scripts or "save for screen".
Then send your order "artboard1- 20pcs. artboard2- 5 pcs" and so on.

Comment: Why is PDF more closed than AI? I mean its more open it even embeds the fonts

Comment: Let's assume you have two professional tools for edition. Illustrator and Acrobat. To edit file in illustrator you just need to open it. At start it ask "hey, this color gamut you know, is something else, want to switch to something different?". Then, the pictures are not embed, try printing it now.  But you press print anyways. Did you checked the color management? Because there Illustrator choose the colors. Also the size of your print? Decided by driver. In Ai all options are open. in pdf you need to make much more steps to even change text.

Comment: Idont dispute it being more suited a s a print container. But its still just a open vector format you can open it justr as well in AI, hell unless you check ai compatibility when you export teh PDF is a AI file

Comment: Yes and no. You can open pdf in AI even if it don't have capabilities checked and change it. But to open ai you use program that from start, open it for editing.  Pdf is a format that can be viewed and send for printing without even preview. It's an EPS file. Also information in pdf, when prepared correctly, is limited to WYSWYG. You can't by accident move the photo inside frame and show that uncle in KKK uniform.

Comment: PDF is most definitely not a EPS file. As far as tech goes EPS is superior bit sadly neglected since its a danger to Adobe. Anyway you can make a AI just as uneditable as a PDF.

Comment: Pdf use subset of PS, thought shortcut in calling it EPS.  You can do anything. The answer is time and effort you need to put into. Time and effort in, possibly, having bad print with handling AI is close to 0 as all you need to do is to open it. Or even not open as sending AI file to RIP that could (unlikely) process it will exceed RIP allot time for page processing. 2,5 MB Ai file is 347 KB pdf. To make thing short: pdf can be printed as it is. AI must be printed from "edit mode". and there are to many variables.

Comment: Actually its not a subset of PS just code turned to markup, with different tags. The same set is used by SVG path so is SVG path postscript? You have to remember i write, PS by hand, i also write PDF by hand though its a bit anoying to calculate the bit offsets in the dictionary at the end. And i write SVG by hand.